# Xamarin.Forms: how to to create a "prohibited" sign with labels and font icons?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, icons, label

I develop a **Xamarin.Forms app** and I'm looking for an **icon** allowing me to display if an event is **free of charge or not**...

As I didn't found anything in the commons font icons like FontAwesome, Ionicons or Material, I've decided to create a **"custom" icon with labels**.

For this, I've choosen:

- for a paid event: the "€" symbol in a thin circle
- for a free event: the "€" symbol barred with a backslash ("\") in a thin circle

In the first case, there is no problem:

```
<Grid Margin="1,0"
      ColumnSpacing="0"
      RowSpacing="0"
      HeightRequest="14"
      >
    <Label 
        Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.CircleThin }"
        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        Opacity="1"
        FontSize="14"
        TextColor="{  DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" />
    <Label 
        Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.Euro }"
        FontSize="8"
        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"                                                                                 
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" />
</Grid>
```

But it's more difficult in the second case, as there are differences between iOS and Android rendering:

```
<Grid Margin="1,0"
      ColumnSpacing="0"
      RowSpacing="0"
      HeightRequest="14"
      >
    <Label 
        Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.CircleThin }"
        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        Opacity="1"
        FontSize="14"
        TextColor="{  DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" />
    <!-- Backslash -->              
    <Label 
        Text="\" 
        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        Rotation="-22"
        TextColor="{  DynamicResource BaseTextColor }"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        >
        <Label.FontSize>
            <artina:OnOrientationDouble>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <On Platform="iOS">13</On>
                    <On Platform="Android">12</On>
                </OnPlatform>
        </Label.FontSize>
        <Label.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="Android">0,0,0,0.5</On>
                <On Platform="iOS">0.5,0,0,1.5</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Label.Margin>
    </Label>                
    <Label 
        Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.Euro }"
        FontSize="8"
        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"                                                                                 
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" />
</Grid>
```

With this, I get a result that is correct, but not perfect:

- on Android:

[image: Android screenshot]

*("Gratuit" represents the free icon)*

- on iOS:

[image: iOS screenshot]

*("Gratuit" represents the free icon)*

In addition, if I need to use an higher size for this icon, I must redefine each parameter of the backslash.

***Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?***

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks quite error prone and probably too heavy for the system. That's a lot of layout and render calls for such a small icon. What you should do, is create a custom control with [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) and handle the drawing yourself. [Here'a a great article](https://blog.xamarin.com/drawing-with-skiasharp/) from Xamarin, outlining how to get started with the library.

Also, here's a collection of additional guides covering everything you need to implement the icon (drawing a circle, text and a line):

[Using SkiaSharp in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/)